# does utf8_unicode_ci support turkish in mysql?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf

Does `utf8_unicode_ci` support **turkish** in `mysql`?
If not, please advice which character encoding format should I use.

Thanks...

Comment: How about just trying it?

Comment: placed a close vote to the highly agreed upon dupe reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `utf8` *CHARACTER SET* handles Turkish.  The `utf8_unicode_ci` *COLLATION* will order things in some manner.  So, in that sense, yes.  But...

There is also `utf8_turkish_ci`, which differs in the handling of at least these: `ÇçÖöğşÜü`.  For example `Ü` is somewhat like a letter between `U` and `V` instead of being treated as equal to `U`.

Reference:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll

If you are dealing with a lot of languages, `utf8_unicode_ci` may be a good compromise.  If dealing mostly with Turkish, use `utf8_turkish_ci`.

Comment: Oh, and the dotted/dotless `Iı` are also different.  Revised collation details:  mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Comment: I need to support umlaute from every language. I am using `utf8_unicode_ci` but it seems that Turkish umlauts are not found by simple search. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='Yilmaz'` won't find `Yılmaz` for example. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59211363/2311074