# MySQL does not treat ı as i?

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, collation

I have a user table in MySQL 5.7.27 with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

Unfortunately, ı is not threaded as i for example, the below query won't find `Yılmaz`

```
select id from users where name='Yilmaz';
```

I do not have the problem with other umlautes like `ä` and `a`. For example the two queries give the exact same result.

```
select id from users where name='Märie';

select id from users where name='Marie';
```

I cannot simply replace `ı` by `i` and to the search, because then I would not find users with the name `Yılmaz`.

Do I have to use different collation to support all umlaute?

Here are some more information about the unicode letters:

```
code    | glyph |decimal |  html   | description
U+0131  |  ı    |305     |&inodot; |  Latin Small Letter dotless I
U+0069  |  i    |105     |-        |  Latin Small Letter I
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell just by inspection what those letters are. Could you add the Unicode code points and their names to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33630106/476

Comment: @deceze thank you, but I guess if I use Turkish collation, then I will get into trouble with other umlautes? I need to support umlautes from all countries.

Comment: @JGNI I have attached a detailed description of the unicode umlautes in the question.

Comment: maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761321/916000

Comment: @TahaPaksu I tried it, but it didn't work either. I have character set `utf8mb4` so I had to use `utf8mb4_bin`, but `bin` is the most restrictive collocation anyway.

Comment: did you try the `LIKE` operator only?

Comment: @TahaPaksu I tried `SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE name LIKE ('%Yilmaz%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin)`

Comment: But I mean without the COLLATE keyword? The string in the cell is already utf8mb4_bin collated, and when you convert the input collation to utf8mb4_bin, it'll look for an exact match. If you don't specify the collation, maybe it'll try to get all variants to match.

Comment: Ok, new info, you can query with a different collation for that specific query like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607164/916000. So can you try : `select id from users where name='Yilmaz' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: @Taha so only `LIKE` operator did not work either. I tried your last comment and to my surprise, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Yilmaz' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci` actually works!! But I am highly confused, because the column `name`has collation set as `utf8mb4_general_ci`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203750/discussion-between-adam-and-taha-paksu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html , I see that `ı=i` in 3 collations:  utf8_general_ci, utf8_general_mysql500_ci, utf8_turkish_ci.  However, for the turkish collation, `I=ı` sorts before other accented I's.  In all other collations `ı` sorts after all I's, as if it is treated as a separate letter.

Meanwhile `İ=I` in all collations except utf8_turkish_ci.

The plot thickens with MySQL 8.0.  utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci (only) has this ordering:

```
I=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=Ĩ=Ī=Ĭ=Į=ı sort before  i=ì=í=î=ï=ĩ=ī=ĭ=į=İ
```

Meanwhile `ä=Ä` and they match most other accented A's for most collations (including the Turkish ones).

Bottom line:  It seems that utf8[mb4]_general_ci is the only collation in 5.7 or 8.0 that will always treat a dotless-i (or dotted-I) equal to a 'regular i/I *and at the same time* ignore umlauts.

Caveat:  The "general" collations do not test more than one character at a time.  That is, a "non-spacing umlaut" plus a vowel will not be treated as equal to the combination.

In that link...  The one character `æ` is sorted the same as the two letters `ae` for some collations.  That's indicated by:  `Aa  ae=æ  az`.  In about half of the other collations, the character  `æ`  is treated as a separate letter; this is indicated by it being after `az` and before `b`.  Or even after `zz` for Scandinavian collations.  This separate letter concept sometimes applies to letter pairs, for example `cs` (Hungarian) and `ch` (traditional Spanish).

Comment: That is perfect, this page is exactly what I was looking for. So in short, there is unfortunately no collation that rules them all. Maybe I need to do something like this: `select * from .. where (a = b COLLATE utf8_general_ci )or where a=b;`?

Comment: Why are there multiple columns in the table? What means `ae`, `az` ,`bz`etc?

Comment: @Adam - I added to my answer to explain ae, az, etc.

Comment: @Adam - and...  True, no single collation.  (But the 4 I's in Turkish is a bit tricky.)  Using an `OR` with two different collations will lead to a full table scan; that is, no index can be used.